# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError instantiating ReverseGeocodeRequest [Android SDK]

Tags: runtime-error, here-api

I am trying to use Here API ReverseGeoLocation and after i added the package to my project and try to run an example from the Documentation starting to get this runtime error.

> Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject.project">


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>



    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="XXXXX"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="XXXXX"/>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXX />

        <activity
            android:label="Na Estrada"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.BemVindoActivity">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.Cadastrar1Activity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:name=".activity.Cadastrar2Activity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.MenuActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.InicialActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.InicioFimTrajetoActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.OperacaoActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.DetalheDoEventoDeEmergenciaActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.DetalheDaParadaPlanejadaActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.DetalheDaRotaActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.ImagensActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:name=".activity.ParadaPlanejadaActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.FinalizarParadaSenhaActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.FinalizarParadaActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.RotasActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".activity.EventosActivity"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

> My build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.naestrada.project"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
// Jar libs
implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


// Support libs
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

// Supernova UI Toolkit
implementation 'io.supernova:android-ui-toolkit:1.0.1'

// Play Services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
// Play Services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'


implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.11'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25'

// Page Control
implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0'

implementation 'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.15.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

// Unit tests dependencies
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

// Integration tests dependencies
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'



}
```

> And my Code.

```
  private void onTirarFotoPressed() {
        try {
            // Implementation of ResultListener
            class ReverseGeocodeListener implements ResultListener<Address> {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Address data, ErrorCode error) {
                    if (error != ErrorCode.NONE) {
                        // Handle error
                    } else {

                        Alert.OkDialog(Sys.lastContext(),"",data.toString());

                        // Process result data
                    }
                }
            }
            if (location!=null) {

                GeoCoordinate hlocation = new GeoCoordinate(
                        location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude()
                );


                ResultListener<Address> listener = new ReverseGeocodeListener();
                // EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE
                ReverseGeocodeRequest request = new ReverseGeocodeRequest(hlocation);
                if (request.execute(listener) != ErrorCode.NONE) {
                    // Handle request error

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Alert.OkDialog(this,"",ex.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

> Error stackTrace:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.naestrada.project, PID: 1148
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.here.android.mpa.internal.cl.<init>(PlacesBaseRequest.java:60)
        at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ds.<init>(PlacesReverseGeocodeRequest.java:56)
        at com.here.android.mpa.search.ReverseGeocodeRequest.<init>(ReverseGeocodeRequest.java:38)
        at com.naestrada.project.activity.OperacaoActivity.onTirarFotoPressed(OperacaoActivity.java:215)
```

Everithing seems to be fine, application build, but when i click on a button to execute the request, i get this error deep down into one of the classes of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Have forgott to initialize MAP. If you are not using the map, only wanna use other resources of the API initializa MapEngine by in your onCreate method:

```
MapEngine mapEngine = MapEngine.getInstance();
ApplicationContext appContext = new ApplicationContext(context);
mapEngine.init(appContext, new OnEngineInitListener() {
  @Override
  public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
      // Post initialization code goes here
    } else {
      // handle factory initialization failure
    }
  }
});
```